# [UITableViewCell otherFeeLblName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc45009a000

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have used `UITableViewController` with static cells and in that in two section i have dynamic xib cell.It is working fine in all iOS phone devices but in iPad its crashing.

> [UITableViewCell otherFeeLblName]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fc45009a000

```
    if (indexPath.section == 2 && defaultsOtherFees.count>0 && (flatRateStatus !=YES)) {  OtherFeeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OtherFeeCell"];
    NSDictionary *otherFeeDict = defaultsOtherFees[indexPath.row];

    if (otherFeeDict.count>indexPath.row) {

        NSString *otherPriceDescription = [otherFeeDict objectForKey:@"otherPriceDescription"];
        cell.otherFeeLblName.text = otherPriceDescription; //crashes on ipad


        cell.delegate = self;


    }

    return cell;
}

if (indexPath.section == 4) {

    RemarkCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RemarkCell"];
    NSDictionary *dict = remarksArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}else
{
    return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: Please put some code of what you have done.

Comment: @ChitraKhatri this is the code written in cellForRow

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the custom class is not sufficient, you have to cast it

```
OtherFeeCell *cell = (OtherFeeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OtherFeeCell"];
```

Comment: Then the class of the custom cell is not set properly in Interface Builder.